# Infinite excel columns that refuse to leave no matter what I do

Tags: microsoft-excel

as the title says, I have xfd number of columns, and nothing I do can get rid of them. I cannot add the excel doc here, as it contains sensitive info, and I apologize for that. I have tried everything I can, and no matter what, the xfd column remains there. I cleared all formatting, cleared all data, deleted, saved, reloaded, etc. to no avail. I would add data to 2 random columns, and then delete the columns between them. the data would then show as being next to each other, meaning all columns in between were successfully deleted, but column xfd was still there, mocking me.

I have begun to have nightmares of all the empty columns. please send help.

Comment: I mean... it sounds like you're joking. But if it's *really* bothering you, then select the columns that are mocking you and right-click/hide them.

Comment: ^^^^ The size of the sheet is set.  If you delete a column a new empty one will be added to the end.  There will always be a `XFD` column.  As stated by @FlexYourData the only method to not "SEE" the columns is to hide them.  The columns still exist just are not visible.

Comment: The biggest issue is I can't insert new columns, as it says I'll push non empty cells off. Another issue is the scroll bar, which is basically useless now.

Comment: You can also select the columns you want and paste them on another sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really shouldn't bother you, as the most right column in an Excel spreadsheet is fixed (And the same applies to rows). If you're worried about the files size, you should know that extra data isn't allocated as long as you haven't assigned any value/formula (or any cell style etc.) in those columns.

When you delete a column, you only delete the data that was on that column (within its cells style) and move the columns to its right one column to the left.

If you would still wish to **hide** those "extra columns", follow the next steps:

1. Select the **most left** column that you wish to hide (select the whole column by pressing the column header).
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. This will select all the remaining empty columns to its right (Notice that if there'll be any non-empty column in this range, the selection will be stopped on the first non-empty column).
3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or *Right click* -> *Hide* to hide the selected columns.

Comment: I should have clarified. I need the cells gone, because I can no longer insert columns for more data, as I'll push nonempty cells off. I've tried the above already, didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Are you saying that you're using ALL the columns, from A to XFD? These are about 16K columns! If so - how are you getting to these much columns? Perhaps we can figure a better way of using the spreadsheet.

Comment: That's the thing, 99 percent of those columns are empty. Excel does not believe them to be, and gives me the error. I'm only using to colmun AW

Comment: Please elaborate on the error you're getting (will be best if you'll also add it on the question itself) - can you post a screenshot / write down what it says, and when does it appear?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it, by restarting excel entirely and using your fix. thank you!